# How to find the difference between maximum and minimum of a time signal, having only Fourier series cofficients

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

I currently know the Fourier coefficients of a signal $c_n$, from the exponential Fourier series of this form: $$f(t) = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} c_ne^{in\omega t}$$

Using these Fourier coefficients, I would like to know how I can calculate the difference between the maximum and minimum amplitudes of the time domain signal. I can use the coefficients $c_n$ to find the time domain signal and find its minimum and maxium, however I am sure there is another more efficient way to do it using only the coefficients and superimposing the amplitudes of all orders.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I think you will only be able to find loose bounds (not exact numbers) for the minimum and maximum, unless you do reconstruct $f(t)$. For example, the max will be less than $\sum_{\forall n} |c_n|$, but this will not be a tight bound (the max will almost certainly be less than this).

Comment: I'm thinking that any means of estimating the bounds that are tighter than Peter's suggested bound would either require the signal to have distinct features (like a few dominant components in the spectrum) or would require more computation than just doing an inverse FFT.  I'd love to be wrong, though.

Comment: And the inverse FFT is certainly more efficient than superimposing the amplitudes of all orders.

Comment: If the phase is 0 and polarity is the same, so that all $c_n$ are real and non-negative, you might be able to say that the peak-to-peak is $2\sum c_n$.

Comment: @PeterK. thanks for the welcome. I am led to believe that I might as well transform the signal to the time domain in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If your function $$f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{in\omega t}$$ has an infinite number of coefficients, then I'm not sure you're going to be able to come up with better bound than
$$|f(t)| \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_n|$$
unless you have some additional structure to the $c_n$ you can make use of.

If you have a finite number of $c_n$ then computing the FFT over the coefficients and then reaching for the minimum and maximum value would be fairly efficient. Depending on the accuracy required you may need to include additional zero padding of the FFT to get finer sample spacing near the peaks.

Comment: grapefruit ***is*** very good.  I don't get enough of it.

Comment: [ye](https://youtu.be/VM6sbPUGZms)